# How to compare current date to article created date?

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript

I need a code to compare if current date and time is greater than article created time of joomla.
I have this example code:

```
  function CompareDate() {  
   //            new Date(Year, Month, Date, Hr, Min, Sec);  
   var dateOne = new Date(2020, 03, 20, 11, 00, 00);  
   var dateTwo = new Date(2020, 03, 20, 12, 00, 00);  

   if (dateOne > dateTwo) {  
        alert("Date One is greater than Date Two.");  
    }else {  
        alert("Date Two is greater than Date One.");  
    }  
}  
CompareDate();
```

Where I need:
 'dateOne' to be the current date and time and 
 'dateTwo' to be the article createad date and time

Any help with this?

Comment: Have you searched through our existing pages for datetime insights? We have already spoken thoroughly about server time, utc, and client-side timestamps.

Comment: Based on your answer, this is no longer a javascript question which makes your question Unclear. 
Also, here is a similar post:  https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/18810/12352

Comment: yes Sir this was resolved via php. the post you point to... has nothing similar with my question .

Comment: While not an exact duplicate, it does demonstrate how to compare an article's date to a generated date.  I will disagree that it "has nothing similar".  Your exact scenario is only a more basic generated date.

Comment: the basic of my question was how to fetch an article created time of joomla article in php code, Sir. the other part of code was easy.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you're using an inline script inside a PHP file.
Depending on how you're fetching the creation date of the article, you may need to make some minor modifications:

```
// Get the creation date of the article
// This may need to be changed according to your requirements
$creationDate = $this->item->created;

Joomla\CMS\Factory::getDocument()->addScriptDeclaration('
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
        function CompareDate()
        {
            var dateOne = new Date("' . $creationDate . '");
            var dateTwo = new Date(Date.now());

            if (dateOne > dateTwo)
            {  
                alert("Date One is greater than Date Two.");
            }
            else
            {  
                alert("Date Two is greater than Date One.");
            }  
        }

        CompareDate();
    });
');
```

Comment: yes I'm using inline script inside custom html article. I try your code but now I'm not getting any message which date is greater.

Comment: @viper - Try the updated code. Please report back any console errors.

Comment: I get this error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '>'

Comment: You're going to need to updated your question with some more code then. Cause if I add this to: `administrator\components\com_content\tmpl\article\edit.php` it works perfectly fine.

Comment: this code should work but it contains both php and js code so how could it be separated

Answer (score 0):

Resolved! This is a working php code to compare current date to article created date:

```
$date1 = new DateTime(); $date2 = new DateTime($article->created); if ($date1 > $date2) 
echo $date1->format("Y-m-d") . " is latest than "
        . $date2->format("Y-m-d"); else echo $date1->format("Y-m-d") . " is older than " 
        . $date2->format("Y-m-d");
```